# Two questions about Windows Storage Spaces and Linux

Tags: linux, windows-8, mount, storage

So when I first configured my desktop I only had Windows 8.1 installed. When I installed my second hard-drive (I have Windows 8.1 and Linux on a separate SSD), I made the mistake of making it a [Windows Storage Space](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/storage-spaces-pools).

To put it simply, here are my two questions:

1) Is it possible to mount a Windows Storage Space in Linux? I've done a bit of searching but I couldn't find any utility to allow me to do this. All of the distros I've tried were not able to read from the Windows Storage Space drive. I am currently using Antergos, which is based on Arch Linux.

2) If it is not possible to mount it in Linux, is it possible to convert the Windows Storage Space to a normal partitioned drive without losing all data on the drive? Windows does allow you to delete a drive from a Storage Pool, but warns that you will lose all data on the drive.

Comment: No; it's not possible the file system isn't licensed. Nobody has published a driver and it's very unlikely to happen

Answer (score 1):

1. You cannot mount storage spaces with Linux. Storage Spaces requires Windows 8.1+ OS which handles the file distribution between multiple drives.
2. You can simple remove one drive from your storage pool if you have 1-2 drive resiliency setup when you first created a storage space drive. This way you will not loose data and you can just reformat the drive you don't want it as storage space drive.